# IIS+ASP: Disabling debug mode still allows DEBUG verb

Tags: asp.net, iis

i need to disabled debug mode on my ASP application by simply setting <compilation debug="true".../> to false. I also have custom error pages for 403, 404 and 500. Now, a simple PostMan request to my application with DEBUG verb selected, gives me a 302, which then redirects the user to my error page with 200 OK.

I was expecting 403 with the verb not allowed anymore, instead of 404 or at least 405 (Method not allowed).

And since i have custom error pages for 403, it redirects to my error page then giving 200 OK. Is it possible to skip custom error pages and throw 403 directly if a non-allowed verb is used on IIS?

[image]

Comment: If you use the non-allowed verb in iis, then iis will throw an error page directly, but not necessarily 403, and it seems that you only set a custom error page in asp.net, not in iis, so It will not redirect to your error page in iis, if you need to use a [custom error page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors) in iis, you need additional settings.

Comment: In my case it is 403, but then redirected to my custom 403 page, so it is 200 then. Any idea with those "additional settings" how do handle this case? In a non-allowed verb is used, i want to ignore the custom error pages, so it throws the default 403.

Comment: What I want to confirm is that your custom error page is set up in asp.net or in iis?

Comment: In IIS only. I think it’s doable via asp but it would be nice to do it via the web.config.

Comment: If in iis, you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831363(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831363(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).